# Having trouble installing praw

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

So I'm trying to make a Reddit bot so I have to install praw. the problem is I keep getting this error message:

```
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
```

When I try to install `nose` and `tornado` they also fail, so what am I supposed to do or should I just give up?

Comment: Can you share what error you face when you try to install `nose` and `tornado` ?

Comment: Nose tells me this:

Comment: oops, sorry! the error messages were too long and I took to long to edit, here is what I tried to edit it into:                                                          edit: the error messages are too long for StackOverflow so I included the screenshots for [nose](https://imgur.com/7mxsyKZ) and [tornado](https://imgur.com/hpUCRhz)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install nose, and tornado, which doesn't have to do with PRAW. Can you clarify how this involves PRAW?

Comment: It's because in the `praw` download error tells me it needs `nose` and `tornado`.